# Building and running mac command line application from terminal

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild

I have a Mac command line application, built with XCode. Is it possible to build and run the relevant target from the terminal?

Comment: You're looking for `xcodebuild`.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it with xcodebuild

Comment: See [xcodebuild man pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)